# Not able to understand a concept from Classical Mechanics by H. Goldstein

Tags: classical-mechanics, work, potential-energy

I was reading classical mechanics by H. Goldstein and I came across the calculation of total potential energy of a system of particles. I am not able to understand what this derivation is conveying and how is the math done. I am attaching the text for reference.

[image: Classical Mechanics H Goldstein Page Number 10 and 11]

Comment: This post (v2) seems _too broad._ Could you narrow down what you don't understand?

Comment: Equations 1.32 1.33 and 1.34

Comment: When asking about context of a paper/book/website/etc, please copy the relevant passage and give specific details what you don't understand (see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11144/25301) for more details). Otherwise we can only guess at what you don't understand.

Comment: If I am guessing right then this is a good question. Please make your question explicit. If not, I will vote to close.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality and doesn't work for blind users. In general, what you've posted doesn't show evidence that you made much effort, including the effort to make it clear what your question is. Please use descriptive titles for questions. This title could be improved if it said what the actual topic was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that for future reference we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations on this site. Images of equations are very strongly discouraged and it's not uncommon to get downvoted for using them.  Mathjax is based on Latex which is widely used in science and mathematics publication.

> Equations 1.32 1.33 and 1.34

First remember that everything in bold is a *vector* and everything else is a *scalar*.  Learn the way the [$\nabla$ operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) ("nabla") works - it's very important in theoretical physics.

> $$V_{ij}=V_{ij}(|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j|)\tag{1.32}$$

This is just the statement that potential between two objects depends on the distance between them.

> $$\mathbf{F}_{ji}=-\nabla_{i}V_{ij}=+\nabla_{j}V_{ij}=-\mathbf{F}_{ij} \tag{1.33}$$

Not sure I've copied that notion correctly as the image is poor (another reason we discourage posting images of equations and prefer Mathjax).

The forces between two particles are equal and opposite.  The expressions for forces in terms of potentials are standard and the result follows because of the definition of the form of the potential in (1.32).  The only way to see this properly is to actually work out the math in detail (which would be covered by the homework-rule and you should do to get an understanding of the way it works).

> $$\nabla V_{ij}(|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j|)=(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j) f\tag{1.34}$$

This is simply an expression stating what the author's text does - that the force (the nabla operator on the potential) is a vector along the line between the two particles.  This again follows from the definition (1.32).  $f$ is just a scalar to indicate the form of the result, the particular value would depend on the specifics of the force laws and particles.

Comment: I am really sorry for posting a question vaguely. I will keep in mind all the suggestions while posting my next questions. And thank you for answering my question.